# SFMC Injecting Code in Incorrect Location in Email Template

Tags: css, html, content-builder, template

I am facing an issue in Marketing Cloud  where the code that should be inserted in the `<head>` of my HTML is being placed in the `<body>` when I choose to create a  template base email. This is causing rendering problems in Gmail, as the `<head>` and styles are not being applied correctly. In addition, SFMC is wrapping the head of my template (which has now been moved to the body) in an additional table with two specific classes:

```
class="stylingblock-content-wrapper"><tr> and <td style="padding: 0px; " class="stylingblock-content-wrapper camarker-inner">.
```

Please, how can I prevent SFMC from making these unwanted changes to my code and ensure that the `<head>` and styles are inserted correctly in my email template?